# Make an API call on the group info change in Azure AD

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get notification(probably alert a third party api on any change) when any users group info changes in Azure Ad.

I read about the subscriptions in Microsoft Graph, but from what I read it is per user.

Is it possible to get the group changes for all the users in a tenancy, either by Microsoft graph or any other method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Microsoft Graph change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks), You can [create a subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0) (aka webhook) on all groups (i.e. an `update` subscription on the `groups` resource). This will include notifications for any group membership changes.

Creating the subscription:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

{
  "changeType": "updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://www.example.com/notifications",
  "resource": "groups",
  "expirationDateTime": "2019-04-06T14:55:47.082Z"
}
```

In this example notification, the object with `id` "4300f326-4062-4daf-9b91-018f82e87361" was added to the group with `id`4f747e07-50c1-4797-8eba-a2bb7104bfc4:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "changeType": "updated",
            "clientState": null,
            "resource": "Groups/4f747e07-50c1-4797-8eba-a2bb7104bfc4",
            "resourceData": {
                "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.Group",
                "@odata.id": "Groups/4f747e07-50c1-4797-8eba-a2bb7104bfc4",
                "id": "4f747e07-50c1-4797-8eba-a2bb7104bfc4",
                "organizationId": "1c411c5e-78cc-4e89-af5e-169408a540b8",
                "sequenceNumber": 636899867048350977,
                "members@delta": [
                    {
                        "id": "4300f326-4062-4daf-9b91-018f82e87361"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2019-04-06T14:55:47.082+00:00",
            "subscriptionId": "448ed5dc-73e9-4c5a-9d4f-94bd7c5dd762",
            "tenantId": "1c411c5e-78cc-4e89-af5e-169408a540b8"
        }
    ]
}
```

An here, that same user was removed from the group (note the `@removed` attribute in the item in `members@delta`):

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "changeType": "updated",
            "clientState": null,
            "resource": "Groups/4f747e07-50c1-4797-8eba-a2bb7104bfc4",
            "resourceData": {
                "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Graph.Group",
                "@odata.id": "Groups/4f747e07-50c1-4797-8eba-a2bb7104bfc4",
                "id": "4f747e07-50c1-4797-8eba-a2bb7104bfc4",
                "organizationId": "1c411c5e-78cc-4e89-af5e-169408a540b8",
                "sequenceNumber": 636899869819085879,
                "members@delta": [
                    {
                        "id": "4300f326-4062-4daf-9b91-018f82e87361",
                        "@removed": "deleted"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "subscriptionExpirationDateTime": "2019-04-06T14:55:47.082+00:00",
            "subscriptionId": "448ed5dc-73e9-4c5a-9d4f-94bd7c5dd762",
            "tenantId": "1c411c5e-78cc-4e89-af5e-169408a540b8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Phillippe, thank you for responding. So is the members@delta the userid? Actually I want to know the Group change based on the users. So when a group is added/deleted/modified for any user in a tenancy I want to know the Users name. So that I can pass it to the third party API, so that they can update some stuff at their end.

Comment: I am new to this, but how do you create a notificationURL?

Comment: Is it possible to supply the resource of subscription like usres/groups, so that I can get the notification of group changes based on the user?

Comment: @liroforum I've updated the answer with links to the Microsoft Graph documentation to get you started. Also see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UL0ns7d3bAQ&t=92). Yes, `members@delta`  will contain the IDs of the user added to the group. (Or it could be a group ID if a group was added to the group.) You can use this ID to get the full details for the user (including the name). Watching all groups and waiting for a  user to be added is equivalent to watching all users and waiting for one of them to be added to a group.

Comment: Thanks for the concept Phillippe.